# Compositions of Unitary Linear Mappings

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Question: Let $T : V → V$ be a unitary linear transformation on a finite-dimensional
inner product space $V$ . Prove that there is a unitary linear transformation
$U : V → V$ such that $U ◦ U = T$

Proof: $T$ is unitary implies $[T]$ is normal, and by theorem, there exists a basis $B$ of $V$ such that $[T]_B$ is diagonal. Consider $U = T^{1/2}$, then we show that $U ◦ U = T$. The matrix $U$ must be such that $U_{i,j} = T_{i,j}^{1/2}$ and so $[U]_B$ is diagonal and thus [T] is normal and also unitary.

Is this logic correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct if you are comfortable with square roots of complex numbers.